# How to display a sub menu to the side of a drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a main menu bar that has a drop down menu and that menu has a sub menu. How do I get the sub drop down menu to display to the left of "drop down 2" link in the first drop down menu? I would also like to align the top of the sub menu to the top of the "drop down 2" link. Right now it's appearing below and to the left of the link.

HTML:

```
<img src="#" width="100%" height="100px">

<div class="TopMenuBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Side</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">menu</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">drop down 1</a></li>
          <li class="sub-dropdown"><a href="#">drop down 2</a>
            <div class="sub-dropdown-menu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub drop down 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub drop down 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">drop down 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="SideMenuBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Side</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<h1>h1 Header</h1>
<main>
  <h2>h2 Header</h2>
  <p>Main paragraph</p>
  <a href="#">Main link</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Main list item</li>
    <li>Main list item</li>
    <li>Main list item</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>h2 Header</h2>
  <p>Main paragraph</p>
  <a href="#">Main link</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Main list item</li>
    <li>Main list item</li>
    <li>Main list item</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
.TopMenuBar {
  border: none;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.TopMenuBar>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.TopMenuBar>ul, .dropdown-menu>ul, .sub-dropdown-menu>ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.TopMenuBar>li {
  display: inline;
}

.TopMenuBar a, .dropdown-menu a, .sub-dropdown-menu a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block
}

/* Applys to all links under class TopMenuBar on hover */
.TopMenuBar a:hover {
  background-color: #b14eb1;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-menu {

}

.dropdown-menu, .sub-dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
  background-color: purple;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

}

/* Applys to all links under class TopMenuBar */
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
  display: block;
}

.sub-dropdown:hover .sub-dropdown-menu{
  display: table;
}



.SideMenuBar {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

.SideMenuBar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.SideMenuBar li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  display: list-item;
}

.SideMenuBar li a:hover {
  background-color: #fcbf7e;
  color: black;
}

main {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: table
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

here is a working model at [codepen](http://codepen.io/BrianC987/pen/JExYGN)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your stylesheet.

```
.sub-dropdown{
  position: relative;
}
.sub-dropdown-menu{
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

more here http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/jyRoWB

Answer (score 0):

See This code example, It may help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
      }
      .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
      }
      .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
      }

      .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        float: right;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-left-color: #ccc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
      }
      .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
        border-left-color: #fff;
      }
      .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
        float: none;
      }

      .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
     <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```